# I try to put a news to featured without a second table, it's possible?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a 'news' table with a 'featured' column.
There will always be only one article on the front page. I wonder if it is possible to realize what I want without creating a second table.

I managed to retrieve the last 'news' featured, like this:

```
$articleFeatured = News::published()
        ->where('featured', true)
        ->first();
```

There may be several featured news, this will always be the last posted that will be displayed.

Now I want to display all the news. Including 'featured' news. EXCEPT the last published news marked as 'featured'.

Is it possible to create this kind of condition with Laravel? I tried, but I can't.

```
$articles = News::published()
        ->where('featured', false)
        ->orWhere([
            ['featured', '=', 'true'],
            ['date']… I DONT KNOW
        ])
        ->get();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```
$articleFeaturedID = News::published()
            ->where('featured', true)
            ->first()->id;

$articles = News::published()
            ->where('id', '<>',$articleFeaturedID)
            ->get();
```

Instead of `id` maybe you use `news_id` or something else